# What is the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$ where A and B are subsets of ${1,2,3,4,5}$ such that neither $A \subseteq B$ nor $B \subseteq A $

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I found answers to this question online. They solved it using inclusion and exclusion principle(which I recently discovered).I understood the principle but I confused about how they did it. Help me to understand.

Comment: What are you asking about exactly? How inclusion exclusion works? An explanation to how to use it here? Perhaps you should give a link to an answer you want help understanding?

Answer (score 4):

Work with $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ rather than $\{1,\ldots,5\}$. There are $4^n=2^n\times 2^n$ ordered pairs of subsets $(A,B)$. Of them, $3^n$ have $A\subseteq B$ and $3^n$ have $A\supseteq B$. Also $2^n$ have both. By inclusion-exclusion, those with neither are
$$4^n-3^n-3^n+2^n$$
in number.

Why are there $3^n$ pairs with $A\subseteq B$? For each of $1,\ldots n$, you have three choices. Put it in both $A$ and $B$, put it in $B$ but not $A$, or put it in neither.